# Mapping using date to create a new column in data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I was trying to map two data frame based on the Date. however, I had an error as follow:

> "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index
>   objects"

I am using the following **df1** and create a new column "Fix Week"

```
kickoffDate kickoffTime hometeam_team1 
2016-08-13    11:30:00     Hull City   
2016-08-13    14:00:00  Middlesbrough   
2016-08-13    14:00:00  Middlesbrough   
2016-08-13    14:00:00  Middlesbrough   
2016-08-13    14:00:00  Middlesbrough
```

The **df2** that I am going to map is as follow:

```
Round       Date         Home Team         Away Team 
  1      2016-08-13        Hull             Leicester  
  1      2016-08-13        Burnley          Swansea  
  1      2016-08-13        Crystal Palace   West Brom  
  1      2016-08-13        Everton          Spurs
```

To get a new column, I am using the following code:

```
df1['fix'] = df1.kickoffDate.map(df2.set_index('Date').Round).astype(float)
```

but it gave me error as I mentioned above.

Would anyone advise me?

Thanks

Zep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem your `Date` values are duplicated in `df2`.

So need remove dupes first for unique `Date` rows:

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates('Date')
print (df2)
   Round        Date Home Team  Away Team
0      1  2016-08-13      Hull  Leicester

df1['fix'] = df1.kickoffDate.map(df2.set_index('Date').Round).astype(float)

print (df1)
  kickoffDate kickoffTime hometeam_team1  fix
0  2016-08-13    11:30:00      Hull City  1.0
1  2016-08-13    14:00:00  Middlesbrough  1.0
2  2016-08-13    14:00:00  Middlesbrough  1.0
3  2016-08-13    14:00:00  Middlesbrough  1.0
4  2016-08-13    14:00:00  Middlesbrough  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks Jez. it is you again. I really appreciate that.
By the way, if i changed the column "fix" to interger type by doing **.astype(int)**. but i cannot.
how to change to integer type.

Comment: @Zephyr - I think it is not possible because some NaNs values. Reason is some dates from `df1.kickoffDate` does not exist in `df1.date` column

Comment: Thanks Jez. I will find another way to sort this out.